# Default value of user.getPhoneNumber() function firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to check if user with email authentication has a phone number set in user profile.
I try `if(user.getPhoneNumber() == null{
//do this
}`
but it is not working for me... So i want to know what is default value of it
or how can i make it in another way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.getPhoneNumber()` returns a `String`. The default value is an empty `String` which is not null. Use either

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getPhoneNumber())){
//do this
}
```

or

```
if("".equals(user.getPhoneNumber())){
//do this
}
```